# Are there infinitely many natural numbers not covered by one of these 7 polynomials?

Tags: nt.number-theory, covering

Consider the following polynomials:
$$
f_1(n_1, m_1) = 30n_1m_1 + 23n_1 + 7m_1 + 5\\
f_2(n_2, m_2) = 30n_2m_2 + 17n_2 + 13m_2 + 7\\
f_3(n_3, m_3) = 30n_3m_3 + 23n_3 + 11m_3 + 8\\
f_4(n_4, m_4) = 30n_4m_4 + 11n_4 + 29m_4 + 11\\
f_5(n_5, m_5) = 30n_5m_5 + 29n_5 + 17m_5 + 16\\
f_6(n_6, m_6) = 30n_6m_6 + 19n_6 + 7m_6 + 4\\
f_7(n_7, m_7) = 30n_7m_7 + 31n_7 + 13m_7 + 13\\
$$
where each $n_1, m_1,..., n_7, m_7 \in \mathbb{N}$

How can I prove that  $\left\vert{\:\mathbb{N} \setminus (f_1 \cup f_2\: \cup\: ... \cup \:f_7)\:}\right\vert = \infty$?

Comment: The $30$ in those polynomials is suspicious and the fact that the degree one terms have coefficients which are all units modulo $30$ is also peculiar. Have you tried reducing the equations $\pmod{30}$?

Comment: This reads a bit like a homework problem.  Please read meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/70, and think about moving your question to our sister site, Math.StackExchange.

Comment: @stijn: if you reduce modulo 30, the first polynomial becomes $7(m_1-n_1)+5$ which is surjective on $\mathbb Z/30 \mathbb Z$ since $(7,30)=1$. So you can't get anything this way.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I'll look into reducing mod 30 and I'll move the question to Math.stackexchange.

Comment: In my opinion the problem is interesting and suitable for MO.  I don't know where these polynomials come from, and maybe I am missing something that those voting to close have seen.  The general problem of understanding what numbers are not of the form $axy+bx+cy$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are given and $x$ and $y$ run over ${\Bbb N}$ seems interesting to me, and I don't know the answer to it.  I vote to reopen.

Comment: Thanks @Lucia! I agree that understanding the general problem of numbers in $\mathbb{N}$ not of the form $axy + bx + cy + d$ is an interesting. I know the problem seems very specific but its just a sub problem of another very general problem.  Something to note about these types polynomials is that they can be seen as generators for infinitely many arithmetic progressions. For example, $f_1(0,m) = 7m + 5$, $f_1(1, m) = 37m + 28$ and so on. So this question can be seen as asking about whether infinitely many arithmetic progress of a certain form are a partial covering.

Comment: Crossposting: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775663/are-there-infinitely-many-non-negative-integers-not-covered-by-one-of-these-7-po.

Comment: I would appreciate any recommendations for current literature on this topic.

Comment: I agree with Lucia on this and also vote to reopen. I have this problem in a corner of my mind since yesterday and don't find the answer obvious (it may still be and I may be missing it, of course). I think it would help, however, if joebloggs added a sentence telling us where these polynomials come from and why he expects that they miss infinitely many integers.

Comment: Thanks for the vote @Joël! The answer is also not obvious to me. These polynomials come from a series of substitutions, which is why they look so particular. I expect the answer to be in the affirmative for a couple of reasons. These specific coefficients and the leading $n*m$ term seem very constraining on possible values for each $f$. Also, if the answer is in the negative then the set is closed under addition and multiplication for every element greater than some $n_0$. This seems highly unlikely to me.

Comment: For what it's worth: up to $10^7$ there are $1254699$ numbers missing from these polynomial values.  So maybe there are infinitely many missing.  For references to the current literature, I don't know any directly related, but for recent work on covering congruences see the paper by Bob Hough (on arXiv), and work of Filaseta, Ford et al in J. Amer. Math. Soc from a few years back (referenced in Hough's paper).

Comment: @Lucia thanks for the reference and the numerical evidince! I'll look into those papers.

Comment: What are stats on f_1?  in particular, for j from 1 to 10, how many values and with what multiplicities does range f_1 intersect (10^j, 10^{j+1}] have? (Just f_1 please, not ready for the other f's yet.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Notice that
$$30\cdot f_1(n_1,m_1) = (30\cdot m_1+23)\cdot (30\cdot n_1+7) - 11\\
30\cdot f_2(n_2,m_2) = (30\cdot m_2+17)\cdot (30\cdot n_2+13) - 11\\
30\cdot f_3(n_3,m_3) = (30\cdot m_3+23)\cdot (30\cdot n_3+11) - 13\\
30\cdot f_4(n_4,m_4) = (30\cdot m_4+11)\cdot (30\cdot n_4+29) + 11\\
30\cdot f_5(n_5,m_5) = (30\cdot m_5+29)\cdot (30\cdot n_5+17) - 13\\
30\cdot f_6(n_6,m_6) = (30\cdot m_6+19)\cdot (30\cdot n_6+7) - 13\\
30\cdot f_7(n_7,m_7) = (30\cdot m_7+31)\cdot (30\cdot n_7+13) - 13
$$

These representations imply that the polynomials cannot represent integers $k>0$ such that $30k \pm 11$ and $30k + 13$ are primes. There are likely infinitely many such prime constellations. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeConstellation.html

P.S. The polynomial $f_4(n_4,m_4)$ is the only one, whose representation has $+11$ as a free term. If it were $-11$ or $-13$ as in the other representations, then we would need existence of infinitely many twin primes of the form $(30k+11,30k+13)$.

Comment: Excellent!  And for the general problem of $axy+bx+cy$, one multiplies through by $a$ and gets $(ax+c)(ay+b)-bc$, so that the numbers missed by such polynomials are again closely related to shifted primes.

Comment: This factoring trick is called "completing the rectangle".

Comment: Great response @Max!

Comment: To go a step away from the prime triple conjecture.

$f_1$ and $f_2$ allow that 
$30n+11$ contains prime factors $p\equiv 1,11,19,29 \mod 30$. 
$f_3,f_5,f_6,f_7$ together are more restrictive,  
All possible prime factors are forbidden,
 
For $f_4$: $30n-11$ may contain  
prime factors $p\equiv 1, 7, 19, 13\mod 30$.

(Note: 1,11,19,29 and 1,7,19,13 are both multiplicative subgroups mod 30).

Hence there is one prime condition, and 2 half-prime conditions, (sieve dimension 2),
which is still undoable. (For sieve dimension 3/2 there is sometimes hope, Iwaniec half dimensional 
sieve).